# Data BACKUP on VERSION UPDATE. App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, version-control, app-store

I am a little curious what happens in the situation when the user downloads a new version of application from App Store. I have an existing app, an eBook reader on the iTunes store (downloaded with customers).

Assuming that the customers have downloaded books to the existing version of application onto their iPad, now that a new version is available on app store & user downloads the same along with the app update i want the user downloaded books(on the previous version) to be backed up when a new updated version is installed.

Currently in my application i'm string these books in Caches Directory of Application Sandbox.

If there is a possibility of doing this, please provide some references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper update will not remove the previous content of your sandboxed folders - hence I do not see a reason for a backup. Proper update means the user uses the iTunes update functionality.

Only once the user entirely removes the previous version and then installs the new version, the sandboxed files of the previous version will be gone.

Comment: Thanks a Ton for ur reply Till, is there any APPLE Documentation.. Supporting this......coz i didn't find any